# Realm Migration

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

Good morning,

I am about to try to clear my preferences file when a change in the database, as there is a series of data that make it impossible to me that the new data are stored in databases.

In MyApplication I have:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .name("PayThunderHologram.realm")
            .schemaVersion(5)
            .migration(new MyMigration())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

In MyMigration I have:

```
public class MyMigration extends AppCompatActivity implements RealmMigration{

   public static SharedPreferences editor;

        @Override
        public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

            editor = getSharedPreferences("Configuración", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor.edit().clear().commit();

        }
    }
```

But when I have a change in database I can not get the preferences file is deleted, giving an error in the application and closing it.

So far what I've been doing to continue with all the evidence it has been clear application data and it works but I would like to automate the way I put up.

**Edit**

Before I had the following to delete only some fields preferences file:

```
.migration(new RealmMigration() {
                    @Override
                    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
                        editor.remove("hologram_id");
                        editor.remove("hologram_ver");
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                })
```

But it does not work

Comment: What is BBDD, and what is the error you get?

Comment: @TimCastelijns BBDD--> Database; the error is trying to find something not to, but because it does not exist in the database but in the preferences file, so you would have to delete the preferences file to re-enter in the database

Comment: What are you storing in the preferences that is related to realm? And why is your migration extending AppcompatActivity?

Comment: @TimCastelijns In preferences save the ID of one of the data Realm, which is active.
My MyMigration extends of AppcompatActivity, otherwise I can not use SharedPreferences

Comment: You're supposed to get the Shared Preferences from the `Application`. Your RealmMigration should not extend Activity.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce For example: `MyApplication.editor.clear().commit();` ?

Comment: I guess that can work if you have a static field in `MyApplication` that you initialize in `onCreate()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have effectively MyApplication `public static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("Configuración", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
...
`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just try and nothing at follow in the same as before

Comment: I never noticed that you specified both a migration AND deleteIfMigrationNeeded. The deletion will be the one that runs.